# Mystery HAVING clause

Tags: ms-access

Can anyone please explain the following HAVING clause from an Access database?  How can Format with all '0' ever return a string of spaces?

```
HAVING Format([PerNr],'0000000') <> '       '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible if field value is set to spaces...

VBA:

```
Dim x As String
x = "       "
MsgBox "x = " & Format(x, "0000000") & " : Len(x) = " & Len(Format(x, "0000000"))
```